# How to build a UI framework with Vue

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, vuejs2

I want to make a UI framework with Vue, but I don't want it to be just any UI framework. I want the User to be able to specify which components they want from the framework. Then I want to be able to bring them into my single-file-templates like this

```
import { component1, component2} from 'framework';
```

I would also like to be able to build this as an npm module.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is probably [this package](https://github.com/vue-land/create-vue-component)

One of the components I did some time ago [uses it](https://github.com/cristijora/vue2-transitions) and it will basically work by default. CVC (first package from above) uses "bili" which is a small wrapper over rollup bundler and creates 3 different types of bundles (umd - browser, common - requirejs and es-ES6 import)

The only thing you are left to do is declare an export in your index file with your components

```
  export {
    component1,
    component2
  }
```

Se [here as a reference](https://github.com/cristijora/vue2-transitions/blob/master/src/index.js#L48)

The only thing to take care here is the css. The default approach will extract css into different css files. 
See [rollup plugin vue](http://vuejs.github.io/rollup-plugin-vue/#/en/2.3/?id=style) on how you could customize what should be done with css. Those options can be specified in the `bili` section [of package json like here](https://github.com/cristijora/vue2-transitions/blob/master/package.json#L67)

If you want to take it one step further and import css along with the component you could look at [Babel plugin component](https://github.com/ElementUI/babel-plugin-component) which is used by Element UI (most popular Vue UI library) to do that.